# Фатальная ошибка Python в cmd

Tags: python, python-3.x, cmd

В Python полный новичок. Когда пытался выполнить код через cmd, мне выдало ошибку:

```
C:\Users\Admin>python test.py
Python path configuration:
  PYTHONHOME = (not set)
  PYTHONPATH = (not set)
  program name = 'python'
  isolated = 0
  environment = 1
  user site = 1
  import site = 1
  sys._base_executable = 'C:\\Users\\Admin\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Py
thon38-32\\python.exe'
  sys.base_prefix = ''
  sys.base_exec_prefix = ''
  sys.executable = 'C:\\Users\\Admin\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38
-32\\python.exe'
  sys.prefix = ''
  sys.exec_prefix = ''
  sys.path = [
    'C:\\Users\\Admin\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38-32\\python38.z
ip',
    '.\\DLLs',
    '.\\lib',
    'C:\\Users\\Admin\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38-32',
  ]
Fatal Python error: init_fs_encoding: failed to get the Python codec of the file
system encoding
Python runtime state: core initialized
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'

Current thread 0x00001ad4 (most recent call first):
<no Python frame>
```

Comment: А что находится в `test.py`?

Comment: Написано print(123)

Comment: Файл `C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\python38.zip` вы сами положили в папку интерпретатора или как установили Python ничего не меняли? Я бы посоветовал удалить Python и установить заново.

Answer (score 0):

Проблема заключается в настройке переменных окружения.
Как видите, в стэктрейсе вам пишет

```
PYTHONHOME = (not set)
PYTHONPATH = (not set)
```

В то время как должны быть указаны пути

**Попробуйте выполнение вашей программы с флагом -E (игнорирование переменных окружения).**

Если вас не устраивает решение такого костыльного плана или оно не работает, разберитесь с корректной установкой Python или вручную установите значения для переменных окружения.

Python для своей корректной работы должен автоматически под себя провести некоторые настройки. Одна из них - это выставление переменных окружения для чтения библиотек и т.д. **Могу посоветовать вам удалить все установленные версии Python, с официального сайта загрузить .exe установщик и установить, следуя инструкциям.**

Также, поскольку вы сказали, что вы новичок в Python, я подскажу вам: **При установке Python ставится также простейшая IDE для работы с ним. Чтобы запустить ее, введите в поиск Windows "IDLE" и запустите нужную версию.** Там вы можете пользоваться интерпретатором, выполняя строчные команды, или создать новый файл, выполнив его содержимое в интерпретаторе одним нажатием кнопки F5.

Или же по хардкору покопайтесь в конфигурационных файлах и программах python и **измените значение переменной окружения PYTHONPATH** на путь к вашим библиотекам.

Comment: Спасибо! Попробую для начала переустановить, а если такая ошибка будет снова, то вы мне дали примерное направление решения проблемы:)

Comment: Решено! Спасибо всем большое за помощь! Видимо что-то изначально не так установил. Переустановил – все хорошо

Comment: @user363198, тогда сделайте ответ в котором и напишите что вам помогло :)